# How to use ZingCharts utility with my existing code in ColdFusion 11?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, zingchart, cfchart

I recently migrated my application from ColdFusion 10 to ColdFusion 11. Though the migration was successful, the charts have been destroyed. 
Up until ColdFusion 10 there was a WebCharts JAR file, called `wc50.jar`, in the `\lib` directory. It contained, amongst others, chart modules such as `com.gp.api.jsp.MxServerComponent`. That JAR file is absent from ColdFusion 11. Hence we have decided to update the our "charting code" and decided to use the new ZingChart.

ZingChart is JSON based. I analysed and found there is a utility in ColdFusion 11 for us to convert the XML stuff to JSON. The name of the utility is `cfchart_xmltojson.bat`. So this is my analysis by far. **My question is - how to run/use this utility to do conversion and then modify my charting code?**

My current charting code look something like this:

```
<cfsaveContent variable="chartStyle">
    <cfoutput>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <frameChart isMultiline="false" is3D="#is3D#">
            <frame outline="##666666"/>
            <yAxis scaleMin="0" scaleMax="100"/>
            <legend allowSpan="true" equalCols="false" placement="Right" isMultiline="true">
                <decoration style="None"/>
            </legend>
            <cfif ShowPyramidNums>
                <dataLabels style="value" placement="Inside" font="Arial-12-bold" >

                </dataLabels>
            </cfif>
            <elements place="Stacked" shape="PyramidCut" shapeSize="100">
                <movie framesPerSecond="2"/>
                <cfset sPerfCtr = 0>
                <cfloop index="i" from="#q_PerformanceDetailsByTemp.RecordCount#" to="1" step="-1">
                    <series index="#Evaluate(sPerfCtr)#">
                        <paint color="###q_PerformanceDetailsByTemp.ChartColor[i]#"/>
                    </series>
                    <cfset sPerfCtr = sPerfCtr+1>
                </cfloop>
            </elements>
            <table>
                <decoration style="Shadow"/>
            </table>
            <background maxColor="white"/>
            <decoration foreColor="white" backColor="##90FFFF"/>
            <popup showOn="Disabled" isAntialiased="true"/>
            <paint palette="Transluent" paint="Plain" max="52"/>
        </frameChart>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsaveContent>
<cfsavecontent variable="chartModel">
    <cfoutput>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <XML type="default">
            <COL>Fall</COL>
            <COL>Winter</COL>
            <COL>Spring</COL>
            <cfset over100FallFixed = false>
            <cfset over100WinterFixed = false>
            <cfset over100SpringFixed = false>
            <cfloop index="i" from="#ArrayLen(PerfStats)#" to="1" step="-1">
                <cfset rowVal = Evaluate((1/q_PerformanceDetailsByTemp.recordCount)*100)>
                <cfif isDefined("over100Alert")>
                    <!--- This set of if statements is to modify value to show triangle correctly --->
                    <!--- Without this modification, the total ia 100.1 which cuts off the top of the triangle --->
                    <cfif right(PerfStats[i].FallPercentage, 1) GT 0 AND NOT over100FallFixed>
                        <cfset PerfStats[i].FallPercentage = PerfStats[i].FallPercentage - .1>
                    </cfif>
                    <cfif right(PerfStats[i].WinterPercentage, 1) GT 0 AND NOT over100WinterFixed>
                        <cfset PerfStats[i].WinterPercentage = PerfStats[i].WinterPercentage - .1>
                    </cfif>
                    <cfif right(PerfStats[i].SpringPercentage, 1) GT 0 AND NOT over100SpringFixed>
                        <cfset PerfStats[i].SpringPercentage = PerfStats[i].SpringPercentage - .1>
                    </cfif>
                    <ROW col0="#PerfStats[i].FallPercentage#" col1="#PerfStats[i].WinterPercentage#" col2="#PerfStats[i].SpringPercentage#">% #PerfStats[i].Name#</ROW>
                <cfelse>
                    <ROW col0="#round(PerfStats[i].FallPercentage)#" col1="#round(PerfStats[i].WinterPercentage)#" col2="#round(PerfStats[i].SpringPercentage)#">% #PerfStats[i].Name#</ROW>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        </XML>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfscript>
    ImageName = "TierTrans_" & CreateUUID() & ".png";
    oMyWebChart = createObject("Java","com.gp.api.jsp.MxServerComponent");
    oMyApp = getPageContext().getServletContext();
    oSvr = oMyWebChart.getDefaultInstance(oMyApp);
    oMyChart2 = oSvr.newImageSpec();
    if(NOT Session.PDFIng)
    {
        oMyChart2.width = 650;
    } else
    {
        oMyChart2.width = 550;
    }
    oMyChart2.height= 230;
    oMyChart2.type = "png";
    oMyChart2.style = "#chartStyle#";
    oMyChart2.model = "#chartModel#";
</cfscript>
<cfif NOT DirectoryExists(ImagesDir)>
    <CFDIRECTORY ACTION="CREATE" DIRECTORY="#ImagesDir#">
</cfif>

<!--- Save image to a different location --->
<cfset oSvr.saveBytesTo(oMyChart2,"#ImagesDir##ImageName#")>

<cfoutput><img src="Images/Reports/#ImageName#" border="0"/></cfoutput>
```

It used to draw a chart something like the image below. (The watermark you see is because I copied the `wc50.jar` from ColdFusion 10 directory to ColdFusion 11 lib directory):

[image: Screenshot of old chart]

Comment: (Edit) Just a thought, but why not use ZingCharts directly? That'll avoid having to fix the code all over again the next time Adobe makes changes the charting tools.... I haven't used `cfchart_xmltojson.bat` but the .bat source looks like it just calls the `main()` method of a java class `coldfusion.graph.XMLToJSON` with 2 arguments: path to xml file and full path to the CF `\lib` directory.

Comment: @Ageax: if I use the ZingCharts then I'll have to rewrite the entire charting code which I believe will take sufficient amount of time. I just thought to save the time and use the utility instead. But If i dont get any proper direction on using this utility I would surely then use zingcharts

Comment: Judging by similar upgrade questions, it may take a while to work out the differences regardless.  That said, like I mentioned above the .bat file just calls a java class. It expects two arguments - both full paths: the first points to the xml file to convert and the second to the CF `\lib` directory. (If you're using the .bat file, the second argument is automatically supplied.) What happened when you tried it?

Comment: From the [docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfchart.html):  *"..To perform this conversion, you need to use cfchart_xmltojson.bat .. [usage] `cfchart_xmltojson.bat <xml_file_path>`. The converted JSON style will be created in the same location as the XML file."*